# Ubuntu 19.04 on Lenovo v110 - Lots of error logs, one failed boot and one reported crash

Tags: boot, 19.04, acpi

Every time I boot Ubuntu 19.04, there errors in the logs.
18 of them begins with "ACPI Error"

A few days ago boot failed completely, but worked again after restart.
And now a crash of a program was automatically reported.

Completely new to linux.
But I want to get this fixed!

What info do I need to post here, and what commands in terminal do I use to get the info?

EDIT

Error logs from "dmesg -lerr":

```
[    0.208008] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_PR.CPU0._PPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.208014] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.208018] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_PR.CPU0._PCT], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.208021] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.208024] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_PR.CPU0._PSS], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.208027] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.208030] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_PR.CPU0.LPSS], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.208033] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.208135] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_PR.CPU0.TPSS], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.208150] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.208283] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_PR.CPU0.PSDF], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.208303] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.208305] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_PR.CPU0._PSD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.208308] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.208311] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_PR.CPU0.HPSD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.208313] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.208323] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_PR.CPU0.SPSD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.208326] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    1.064027] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
```

I also see in Ubuntu Logs GUI:

```
Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop  
Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0  
gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
```

Comment: You can list any line in your logs for the latest boot that has the word error in it with journalctl -b-0 | grep error | >> booterrors.txt. You might have to try variations of the capitalisation to get what you want. This will create a file called booterrors.txt. Not all errors (or program crashes) are significant but hard to say without seeing the output. Have you had a single crash or repeated crashes?

Comment: Added logs from dmesg. Couldn't get the above command to work... I have had one crash and one failure to boot. I also sometimes see an errormessage when shutting down.

Comment: Sorry, stupid typo in the command above. Should be journalctl -b-0 | grep error >> booterrors.txt. I don't think you have much to worry about. I don't know much about the ACPI errors but they seem to imply something has already happened rather than something has gone wrong. I've seen errors like the "...spice..." error on my installs. there were no issues that i was aware of that impacted my use of the computer. i never found a solution and eventually gave up looking. Have you googled any of these errors?